# Can I customize the delete warning in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

It's common in Rails apps to have the Destroy action come along with a warning - "Are you *sure* you want to delete this?" The typical code looks like this:

```
link_to("Destroy", "http://www.example.com", :method => :delete, :confirm => "Are you sure?")
```

Is there a way in ActiveAdmin to customize the confirmation string for one model only (not globally)? I see that the string is loaded from the `active_admin.delete_confirmation` translation key. Can the string be model-specific?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can change the string with configuration.
However you can change the default actions:

Index table: https://github.com/activeadmin/active_admin/blob/master/docs/3-index-pages/index-as-table.md

```
index do
  column :title
  actions defaults: false do |post|
    link_to("Destroy", "http://www.example.com", :method => :delete, :confirm => "Are you sure?")
  end
end
```

Show page: https://github.com/activeadmin/active_admin/blob/master/docs/8-custom-actions.md#action-items

```
action_item only: :show do
  link_to("Destroy", "http://www.example.com", :method => :delete, :confirm => "Are you sure?")
end
```

Comment: Turns out we're on 0.4.3 (eek!) so I had to use a [different syntax](https://github.com/activeadmin/active_admin/blob/0173e9001e370467b1ba658cecc41dab24457a63/lib/active_admin/views/index_as_table.rb#L48) but you're right, this is the way to do it.

Answer (score 6):

Since ActiveAdmin 2.7 model-specific translations can be customized by placing them to active_admin.resources group in en.yml.

```
active_admin:
    resources:
        user:
            delete_confirmation: Are you sure?
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also overcome this ActiveAdmin limit via Javascript.

Here an example of `app/assets/javascripts/active_admin.js`:

```
//= require active_admin/base

$( document ).ready(function() {

    $('body.admin_companies a[data-method=delete]').
        data('confirm', 'New confirmation text per model Company.\n Ok?');

    $('body.admin_users a[data-method=delete]').
        data('confirm', 'New confirmation text per model User.\n Ok?');
});
```

where `body.admin_companies` is to limit this confirmation message to views of the model Company.
Similar for `body.admin_users`.

It works both on #index and #show.

The only downside is that it doesn't play well with i18n (if you need multilanguage avoid this solution).